# Grouping date periods in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I run this query in SQL Server:

```
select 
    personeel_nummer as employee_number,
    vanaf_datum as from_date,
    tot_datum as until_date
from 
    personeel_kenmerken
where 
    personeel_nummer = 32600
```

And I get this as result:

| employee_number | from_date | until_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32600 | 2022-10-01 | 2023-02-26 |
| 32600 | 2023-02-27 | 2023-09-03 |
| 32600 | 2023-09-04 | 2023-09-18 |
| 32600 | 2023-10-10 | 2023-10-18 |
| 32600 | 2023-10-19 | null |

I now need a query to see the periods this employee has been with us
2 periods: from 2022-10-01 until 2023-09-18 because all the until_dates and from dates_ are adjacent between them
and from 2023-10-10 until null as the 2nd period (null means infinite in our case)

Expected result:

| employee_number | from_date | until_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32600 | 2022-10-01 | 2023-09-18 |
| 32600 | 2023-10-10 | null |

Can someone help me write a select query that can generate this result?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add some more sample data. For example another employee, someone who doesn't fulfill the requirements.

Comment: This has been asked a billion of times, see gaps and islands and dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t;

CREATE TABLE #t
(
   employee_number  INT 
 , from_date        DATE
 , until_date       DATE
)
;

INSERT INTO #t (employee_number, from_date, until_date)
VALUES
  (32600,  '2022-10-01', '2023-02-26')
, (32600,  '2023-02-27', '2023-09-03')
, (32600,  '2023-09-04', '2023-09-18')
, (32600,  '2023-10-10', '2023-10-18')
, (32600,  '2023-10-19', NULL        )
, (32601,  '2022-10-01', '2023-02-26')
, (32601,  '2023-02-27', '2023-09-03')
, (32601,  '2023-09-04', '2023-09-18')
, (32601,  '2023-10-10', '2023-10-18')
, (32601,  '2023-10-19', NULL        )
;

WITH C1 AS (
  SELECT *, 
         LAG(until_date) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_number ORDER BY from_date) AS lag_until_date
  FROM #t
),

C2 AS (
  SELECT employee_number,
         from_date,
         until_date,
         SUM(CASE WHEN from_date = DATEADD(day, 1, lag_until_date) 
             THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
             OVER (PARTITION BY employee_number ORDER BY from_date) AS grp
  FROM C1
)

SELECT employee_number,
       MIN(from_date) AS from_date,
       NULLIF(MAX(COALESCE(until_date, '12/31/2099')),'12/31/2099') AS until_date
FROM C2
GROUP BY employee_number, grp
ORDER BY employee_number, from_date
;
```

**Result:**

```
employee_number from_date   until_date
32600           2022-10-01  2023-09-18
32600           2023-10-10  NULL
32601           2022-10-01  2023-09-18
32601           2023-10-10  NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

-- SQL Server Query

This query is designed to identify and group employment periods for employees, considering their start and end dates,
and present the results with the relevant employee number, start date, and end date
(or NULL if it's an ongoing employment period). The results are ordered by employee number and employment period.

```
-- DROP TABLE
DROP TABLE  if exists #personeel_kenmerken;

-- CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE #personeel_kenmerken (
  emp INT,
  start_date DATE,
  end_date DATE
);

-- INSERT DATA 
INSERT INTO #personeel_kenmerken (emp, start_date, end_date)
VALUES
  (32600, CONVERT(DATE, '2022-10-01'), CONVERT(DATE, '2023-02-26')),
  (32600, CONVERT(DATE, '2023-02-27'), CONVERT(DATE, '2023-09-03')),
  (32600, CONVERT(DATE, '2023-09-04'), CONVERT(DATE, '2023-09-18')),
  (32600, CONVERT(DATE, '2023-10-10'), CONVERT(DATE, '2023-10-18')),  
  (32600, CONVERT(DATE, '2023-10-19'), NULL),  
  (32601, CONVERT(DATE, '2022-10-11'), CONVERT(DATE, '2023-02-26')),
  (32601, CONVERT(DATE, '2023-02-27'), CONVERT(DATE, '2023-09-03'));
 
-- GAP AND ISLAND QUERY
    WITH PrevValues AS (
        SELECT *,
                IsStart = 
                    CASE WHEN DATEADD(day, -1, start_date) <=
                        LAG(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY emp ORDER BY Start_Date)
                    THEN NULL ELSE 1 END
        FROM #personeel_kenmerken e
    ), Groups AS (
        SELECT *,
          GroupId = COUNT(IsStart) OVER (PARTITION BY emp ORDER BY Start_Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
        FROM PrevValues pv
    )
    SELECT 
      g.emp,
      StartDate = MIN(start_date),
      EndDate = NULLIF(MAX(COALESCE(end_date, '12/31/2099')),'12/31/2099')
      , GroupId
    FROM Groups g
    GROUP BY
      g.Emp, g.GroupId
    ORDER BY emp, GroupId
```

Results

```
emp     StartDate   EndDate     GroupId
32600   2022-10-01  2023-09-18  1
32600   2023-10-10  NULL    2
32601   2022-10-11  2023-09-03  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below query

```
 WITH Cte AS (
    SELECT
        personeel_nummer,
        vanaf_datum,
        tot_datum,
        CASE WHEN vanaf_datum = DATEADD(DAY, 1, LAG(tot_datum) OVER (ORDER BY personeel_nummer, vanaf_datum)) THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY personeel_nummer, vanaf_datum) ELSE 0 END AS GroupChange
    FROM
        personeel_kenmerken
),
Cte2 AS (
    SELECT
        personeel_nummer,
        vanaf_datum,
        tot_datum,
        GroupChange,
        ISNULL(LEAD(GroupChange) OVER (ORDER BY personeel_nummer, vanaf_datum), 0) AS a
    FROM
        Cte
),
Cte3 AS (
    SELECT
        personeel_nummer,
        vanaf_datum,
        tot_datum,
        CASE WHEN GroupChange = 0 THEN vanaf_datum ELSE NULL END AS from_date,
        CASE WHEN a = 0 THEN tot_datum ELSE NULL END AS to_date
    FROM
        Cte2
),
cte4 as
(SELECT personeel_nummer employee_number
    ,MAX(from_date) OVER (PARTITION BY personeel_nummer ORDER BY vanaf_datum) AS from_date,
    to_date

FROM
    Cte3)
    select * from cte4 where to_date is not null
```